# How to send an animated GIF in a card like this in Facebook messenger API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I tried using the generic template, but it does not animate the GIF - this is needed for showing a 'Powered by Giphy' banner in the bottom of the card - like image below.

[animated GIF received in a messenger card/bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmDBM.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have to send an attachment of image instead of a generic template, like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"USER_ID"
  },
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"image",
      "payload":{
        "url":"https://petersapparel.com/img/shirt.png"
      }
    }
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Check out this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/image-attachment

Comment: I do that with no problems, the issue is that I need to display the 'Powered by GIPHY' banner at the bottom of the GIF, which is not possible without a card/bubble....

Answer (score 0):

Two bubbles. First is the image, the second is the advert.